# UITableView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c

I have a UITableView added programmatically to a UIScrollView, this is done like that so i can scroll the scrollview horizontally to show the rows completely, but i don't want the scrollview to scroll vertically, instead, i want the tableview to do so.

I already wrote all the code but the scrollview is scrolling vertically even though i am setting the [scrollView setScrollsToTop:NO]; method.

How can i make the tableview to scroll vertically instead of the scrollview ?

```
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([_scrollableTableView bounds].size.width, [_scrollableTableView bounds].size.height)];
[_scrollView addSubview:_scrollableTableView];
[_scrollView setBounces:NO];
[_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_scrollView setDirectionalLockEnabled:YES];
[_scrollView setScrollsToTop:NO];
[_scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

 _scrollableTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50*([[[_allLiveResults objectAtIndex:0] listOfTitles] count]-3), 25+50*[[[_allLiveResults objectAtIndex:0] listOfParticipants] count]) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

_scrollableTableView.tag = 2;
_scrollableTableView.delegate = self;
_scrollableTableView.dataSource = self;
_scrollableTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 25;
_scrollableTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollableTableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
[_scrollableTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[_scrollableTableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[_scrollableTableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_scrollableTableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Comment: Try setting the contentSize's height to the scrollView's height. Then the vertical scroll should be disabled because there would be nothing to scroll vertically.

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);

Comment: i already did .. this did work but the problem is that the tableView won't scroll down so the other rows will appear @Ashwin

Comment: What is the size of the tableview by the way? Is it more that the scrollview size or view size?

Comment: yes the tableview is larger horizontally and vertically .. but i did put it in a scrollview so i can see the rows completely but vertically i want the tableview to scroll not the scrollview @Ashwin

Comment: U can set the size of tableview as same as scrollview. Ur row would be scrolling inside the tableview and u would be able to scroll the tableview horizontally

Comment: do you mean that i set the scrollview's height the same as the tableview's ? then i should create the scrollview manually .. @Ashwin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82960/discussion-between-ashwin-and-user3783005).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but maybe you want something like this:

[AFTabledCollectionView](https://github.com/AshFurrow/AFTabledCollectionView)

Comment: does this one scrolls each row itself or all together ??

Comment: Each row is scrolled independently

Comment: i want all the rows to scroll together .. thank you anyway for your answer

Comment: What do you mean by all the rows to scroll together? You want to be able to scroll horizontally and all the rows scroll at the same time, like if you had only one single row?

Comment: the thing is that the content of the rows are bigger than the rows .. so i implemented the tableview in a scrollview so i could scroll it horizontally to see the rest of the rows
but my problem is that this scrollview is scrolling vertically so i can see the rest of the rows inside it .. but i want that to happen while the tableview is scrolling vertically not the scrollview